# Parsing html in innerHTML using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get id and parse to get its number after getting the innerhtml like 3 examples below:-

```
var myIHTML = cell[0].innerHTML;

myIHTML = '<input type="submit" name="pic" value="Preview" /><div id="allItems1" style="display: none;"></div>' ;
or
myIHTML = '<input type="submit" name="pic" value="Preview" /><div id="allItems2" style="display: none;"></div>';
or
myIHTML ='<input type="submit" name="pic" value="Preview" /><div id="allItems11" style="display: none;"></div>'
```

I like to get the number from allItems id. like 1, 2, 11 etc.

Comment: What do you mean by parse? Do you mean to convert your string into HTML?

Comment: no, I mean to extract the value. it doesnt matter if i get it in string or number. See my question at last line "I like to get the number from allItems id. like 1, 2, 11 etc"

Comment: Why would you parse it, when you can get it directly from the DOM? `var value = cell[0].querySelector('div').id.replace('allItems','')` will give you what you want.

Comment: You then want to get the ID, `cell.querySelector('[id^=allItems]').id.replace('allItems','')`

Comment: Thanks blex, I got the inner part of html so fast :)                                          .evolutionxbox, your comment gives exactly what I am trying to get in simple way. Thank you, if that was in answer, i would have selected this as answer instead of just upvote. The below answers are now alternatives and will select one of those. Thanks again , you guys rocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your innerHTML back to DOM, so you can search in it and then parse the id. Here is an example:

```
// Create a div to insert back the contents into
var div = document.createElement('div');

// Insert the contents back
div.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="pic" value="Preview" /><div id="allItems1" style="display: none;"></div>';

// Get the element with id starting with allItems
var id = div.querySelector('[id^="allItems"]').id;

// Get the number by replacing non-digits with empty character and then converting the string to integer
console.log( 'Number from id is', parseInt( id.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks your solution, a bit longer but  also worked :) . The simple one is what evolutionxbox suggest above in comments. Selecting your reply as answer as it also give what I am looking for and evolutionxbox answer is in comment.

Comment: I thought you don't have access anymore to `cell` - in your question you say "How to get id and parse to get its number **after** getting the innerhtml like 3 examples below" and that's why I re-create the innerHTML again in DOM. If you still have it, of course it's better (and faster) to directly use it. @AKS

Comment: It makes sense now. thanks for clarification. I understood this aspect now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to parse the string:

```
var elems = $(myIHTML);
```

Then select the elements within using filter():

```
var alItems2Elem = elems.filter('#allItems2');
```

To get the number from the id of the div:

```
var alItemsId = elems.filter('div').attr('id').replace('allItems', '');
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKvjAB)

Read more about `.filter()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: I dont know what is there in filter as it is dynamic and i given couple of samples. elems.filter('#allItems2'); The allItems2 is what i dont know and get it at run time and I need to find/filter 2 in allItems2 . The answer by evolutionxbox is what I was looking for. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: The third example jdoes what the accepted answer does but with a single line of jquery, notice it filters('div')s ou could use filter('[id^="allItems"]') aswell for the same result.